# Can I buy the full (non-community) version of CVXPY somewhere?

Tags: python, portfolio, cvxpy, pypfop

CVXPY is a package that enables convex optimization, but  the community version of CPLEX only supports 1000 variables and constraints (https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.problems.html#id3).

I need to optimize a portfolio larger than 1000, but I can't seem to find information on how to on here: https://www.cvxpy.org/install/

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with cvxpy which is a pure free open source project (focusing on modelling and transformations; not solvers). It has multiple solver backends, one of those being the commercial software cplex (not related to cvxpy). Visit [their homepage](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer). cvxpy itself also links to [external pages](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/#install-with-cplex-support) in regards to cplex. (Before wasting time: If you are doing academic work, there might be acad. licenses, if your company pays: fine; obtaining a license as a private person is rare imho)

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX is only **one of many CVXPY backends** as stated by @sascha in the comment.

If you have academic background (staff, student, teacher, etc), you can request free academic CPLEX via [IBM Data Science](https://www.ibm.com/academic/technology/data-science).

Step by step:

1. Navigate to `Software > ILOG > Download`.
2. Find ILOG that satisfy your need and python version.
3. Install ILOG
4. Find the location of cplex `setup.py` in your ILOG installation and install it using `python setup.py install`.

See ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos).

If you are interested with other backend, see the [installation guide of CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html)